# How do I get an item number from a text input in an ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCTRL">
  <form class="my-form" ng-repeat="item in items" novalidate>
    <h4>{{item.number}}</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.hed"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.subhed">
  </form>
</body>
```

My JS:

```
var app=    angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCTRL",function($scope,$http){
  $scope.items= [
    {
      number: chartNumber,
      hed: '',
      subhed: ''
    }
  ];
});
```

When I type something into the `input` tags, I want to `console.log()` the `item.number` value. How do I do this with AngularJS v1.6.1?

Comment: *When I type something into the `input` tags, I want to `console.log()` the `item.number` value.* What???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-change directive to detect any change in the input value

```
   <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCTRL">
      <form class="my-form" ng-repeat="item in items" novalidate>
        <h4>{{item.number}}</h4>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.hed" ng-change="inputChange(item)"><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.subhed" ng-change="inputChange(item)">
      </form>
    </body>
```

JS

```
var app=    angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCTRL",function($scope,$http){
  $scope.items= [
    {
      number: chartNumber,
      hed: '',
      subhed: ''
    }
  ];
  $scope.inputChange = function(item) {
     console.log(item.number);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.hed" ng-keyup="$parent.inputHandler(item)">
```

your controller:

```
app.controller("myCTRL",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.items= [
    {
       number: chartNumber,
       hed: '',
       subhed: ''
    }
    ];

    $scope.inputHandler = function(item){
        console.log(item.number);
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCTRL",function($scope){
  $scope.items= [
    {
      number: 1,
      hed: '',
      subhed: ''
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      hed: '',
      subhed: ''
    }
  ];
  $scope.log = function(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCTRL">
  <form class="my-form" ng-repeat="item in items" novalidate>
    <h4>{{item.number}}</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.hed", ng-keypress="log(item.number)"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.subhed", ng-keypress="log(item.number)">
  </form>
</div>
```